# Emergency mode after installing new ssd: "failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: no such file or directory..."

Tags: fedora

I installed a new ssd which works fine with Windows (that I need to use for my job). But Fedora 30 enters emergency mode when starting the system. `journalctl -xn` shows the error **"failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: no such file or directory. AVC will be dropped"**.

I assume that the error is related to the new ssd but maybe it is completely unrelated...

Any idea anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was just that I had an old fashioned entry for an existing partition in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1        /mnt/something ...
```

There was of course a new `/dev/sda1` but the filesystem was different which I suppose was the issue. After replacing it with the appropriate `UUID=2C7E200A67DAEA14` everything worked fine.